# insufficient space on device

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-desire, insufficient-memory

I am getting "Insufficinet Space" errors when I try to update whatsapp on my HTC desire. I am running CyanogenMod 7.

My filesystem usage looks like this:

```
df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                   202.8M     32.0K    202.7M   0% /dev
tmpfs                   202.8M         0    202.8M   0% /mnt/asec
tmpfs                   202.8M         0    202.8M   0% /mnt/obb
/dev/block/mtdblock3    250.0M    118.3M    131.7M  47% /system
/dev/block/mtdblock5    147.6M    122.6M     25.0M  83% /data
/dev/block/mmcblk0p2    961.1M     16.0M    896.3M   2% /sd-ext
/dev/block/vold/179:1
                      2.6G    952.7M      1.7G  36% /mnt/sdcard
/dev/block/vold/179:1
                      2.6G    952.7M      1.7G  36% /mnt/secure/asec
/dev/block/dm-0           3.1M      1.6M      1.5M  52% /mnt/asec/com.opera.mini.android-2
/dev/block/dm-1           9.1M      7.2M      2.0M  78% /mnt/asec/com.google.android.apps.maps-1
/dev/block/dm-2          16.2M     14.1M      2.1M  87% /mnt/asec/com.google.android.apps.plus-1
/dev/block/dm-3          20.3M     18.9M      1.4M  93% /mnt/asec/com.google.android.gms-1
/dev/block/dm-4           6.1M      4.9M      1.2M  81% /mnt/asec/org.xbmc.android.remote-1
/dev/block/dm-5           4.1M      2.3M      1.8M  56% /mnt/asec/com.google.android.gm-1
/dev/block/dm-6          17.2M     15.6M      1.7M  90% /mnt/asec/com.whatsapp-2
```

What I would like to know is exactly what partition I need to free up this missing space on. /system and /data all seem to have 25M +, and I am trying to update Whatsapp. The current Whatsapp app is just a little over 10M so should fit as far as I can see from this.

I appreciate that similar questions have been asked on this site before but I have tried various solutions mentioned there already such as removing unused apps and re-mounting the cache partition to the sd card.

Comment: Did you tried clearing the cache and the data stored by the Whatsapp by heading over to the application manager ?

Comment: Clearing the cache and data in the application manager for watsapp freed up 4M in the volume attached to /data. There is now nearly 30M free in /data and still getting the same error

Comment: Also try clearing the dumpstat/logcat file by pressing *#9900# over the dial pad and select the 2nd option dumpstat/logcat. See if it helps you ... :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem.
[insufficient space while updating WhatsApp on CyanogenMod](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/92912/)

If nothing helps, you should show us a log from DDMS.