# insufficient space while updating WhatsApp on CyanogenMod

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.3-jelly-bean, insufficient-memory, application-autoupdate

i hope you can help me with the following problem

I was forced to update the newest version of WhatsApp (26.Dec 2014).
Whatever i tried, update has aborted.
**Error Message: insufficient space**
**Several apps are affected with same error Message.**

---

### **System**

Samsung Galaxy Note 1
CyanogenMod 10.2
Android 4.3.1

**Internal Storage: ~ 500 MB free**

```
Build: cm_n7000-userdebug 4.3.1 JLS36I d43c004b40 dev-keys
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-N7000/GT-N7000:4.0.3/IML74K/ZCLP6:user/release-keys'
Kernel: Linux version 3.0.64-CM-g9d16c8a (build04@cyanogenmod) (gcc version 4.7 (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Dec 14 01:28:24 PST 2013
```

---

### **What i tried already**

- googled and read similar question
- restarted several times
- deleted "WhatsApp\Media" (61 MB) and tried again
- tried "App Cache Cleaner"
- "wipe cache partition" in Recovery mode
- download and install from whatsapp.com/android/ (Version 2.11.481 / 18 MB)

---

### **Update cancelled with same error message**

- WhatsApp
- Chrome Browser
- Dropbox
- Facebook
- Google Maps

### **Update successfully installed at same day**

- Adobe Reader
- Trello

---

### **What happens during install WhatsApp**

**ddms Log**
whatsapp.com/android/
Version 2.11.481
18 MB

```
12-23 23:23:51.905: D/lights(2225): set_light_buttons: 1
12-23 23:23:52.165: I/ActivityManager(2225): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/sdcard0/Download/WhatsApp.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x1 cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity (has extras)} from pid 2445
12-23 23:23:52.340: I/ActivityManager(2225): Start proc com.android.packageinstaller for activity com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity: pid=5172 uid=10034 gids={50034, 1028}
12-23 23:23:52.375: W/ActivityThread(5172): Application com.android.packageinstaller can be debugged on port 8100...
12-23 23:23:52.905: D/lights(2225): set_light_buttons: 2
12-23 23:23:53.500: I/AppSecurityPermissions(5172): Ignoring unknown permission:android.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT
12-23 23:23:53.505: I/AppSecurityPermissions(5172): Ignoring unknown permission:android.permission.STORAGE
12-23 23:23:53.510: I/AppSecurityPermissions(5172): Ignoring unknown permission:com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ
12-23 23:23:53.510: I/AppSecurityPermissions(5172): Ignoring unknown permission:com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE
12-23 23:23:53.510: I/AppSecurityPermissions(5172): Ignoring unknown permission:com.whatsapp.permission.BROADCAST
12-23 23:23:53.745: D/libEGL(5172): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
12-23 23:23:53.745: D/libEGL(5172): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
12-23 23:23:53.750: D/libEGL(5172): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
12-23 23:23:53.750: E/(5172): Device driver API match
12-23 23:23:53.750: E/(5172): Device driver API version: 17
12-23 23:23:53.750: E/(5172): User space API version: 17 
12-23 23:23:53.750: E/(5172): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p1-01rel1 BUILD_DATE=Tue Jul  2 15:06:24 KST 2013 
12-23 23:23:53.775: D/OpenGLRenderer(5172): Enabling debug mode 0
12-23 23:23:53.820: V/RenderScript(5172): 0x40048660 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
12-23 23:23:53.845: I/ActivityManager(2225): Displayed com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity: +1s519ms
12-23 23:24:11.570: D/lights(2225): set_light_buttons: 1
12-23 23:24:11.630: I/ActivityManager(2225): START u0 {dat=file:///storage/sdcard0/Download/WhatsApp.apk cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress (has extras)} from pid 5172
12-23 23:24:11.880: W/InstallAppProgress(5172): Replacing package:com.whatsapp
12-23 23:24:11.915: W/ActivityManager(2225): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///storage/sdcard0/Download/WhatsApp.apk
12-23 23:24:11.975: I/ActivityManager(2225): Displayed com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress: +168ms
12-23 23:24:11.990: D/Finsky(2829): [1] PackageVerificationReceiver.onReceive: Verification requested, id = 1
12-23 23:24:12.030: D/Finsky(2829): [1] WorkerTask.onPreExecute: Verification Requested for id = 1, data=file:///storage/sdcard0/Download/WhatsApp.apk flags=18 fromVerificationActivity=false
12-23 23:24:12.570: D/lights(2225): set_light_buttons: 2
12-23 23:24:22.080: I/PackageManager(2225): Verification timed out for file:///storage/sdcard0/Download/WhatsApp.apk
12-23 23:24:22.080: I/PackageManager(2225): Continuing with installation of file:///storage/sdcard0/Download/WhatsApp.apk
12-23 23:24:22.130: D/Finsky(2829): [1] PackageVerificationReceiver.onReceive: Verification requested, id = 1
12-23 23:24:22.155: D/Finsky(2829): [1] PackageVerificationService.cancelVerificationIntent: Cancel active verification id=1
12-23 23:24:22.415: W/ActivityManager(2225): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///storage/sdcard0/Download/WhatsApp.apk
12-23 23:24:22.415: I/PackageManager(2225): Copying native libraries to /data/app-lib/vmdl-1851828518
12-23 23:24:24.910: D/Volley(2829): [69] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/clientreport/download 0xc9395b26 NORMAL 8> [lifetime=8741], [size=2], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
12-23 23:24:24.910: D/Finsky(2829): [1] 2.onResponse: Verification id=1 response=0
12-23 23:24:24.915: D/Volley(2829): [1] Request.finish: 8745 ms: [ ] https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/clientreport/download 0xc9395b26 NORMAL 8
12-23 23:24:26.795: W/NativeHelper(2225): Could not delete native binary: /data/app-lib/com.whatsapp-2/libwhatsapp.so
12-23 23:24:26.795: W/NativeHelper(2225): Could not delete native binary: /data/app-lib/com.whatsapp-2/libqcom.so
12-23 23:24:26.795: E/PackageManager(2225): Cannot rename native library directory /data/app-lib/vmdl-1851828518 to /data/app-lib/com.whatsapp-2
12-23 23:24:26.800: W/PackageManager(2225): Invalid verification token 1 received
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recognized all affected apps are on internal storage. This problem may occur in the following circumstances:

- Removing battery when the phone is on
- Corrupted battery, instant shutdown of your phone.

Solution:

1. Download and install [SystemCleanup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.SystemCleanup.Inteks.org) (need root)
2. Delete dead data folder for each affected app
3. Try to update again and it will work!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in your log the system is unable to delete certain library files. Because of that it thinks that you do not have enough storage (as deleting a file is considered writing it) and cancels the installation.

If your device is rooted, I would suggest you delete those libraries or fix their permissions/owner and try installing again. If that doesn't work you need to completely format (not delete everything but create a whole new filesystem, referring to the procedure of wiping partitions with CWM recovery) your `/data` partition to fix that problem because not even root would be able to solve that problem (I had this with Shazam once).