# Cannot install Whatsapp - it says insufficient storage available

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, insufficient-memory

I just got a new android phone running 4.4.2 as an interim before I buy another phone. After factory reset, I tried to install Whatsapp. This was the first app that I tried to install and it failed after downloading saying that there was insufficient storage available. I tried doing it multiple times - to the same result.

Free internal memory - 1.1GB. Free phone storage memory - 1.3 GB. No other app apart from the inbuilt apps have been installed. Post this, I installed Facebook Messenger and it works just fine. I don't understand why Whatsapp isn't installing. Another messaging service called Hike Messenger also works fine. Please help!

Just tried installing "Advanced Task Manager" and "Advanced Task Killer" to the same result - insufficient storage memory.

Comment: simple way to fix the issue http://www.scarletfire.co.uk/fix-android-insufficient-storage-available-problem/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is a Dead Data Folder
Download and install **SystemCleanup** on Google Play
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.SystemCleanup.Inteks.org&hl=en

**ROOT ACCESS necessary**

**Delete Dead Data Folder for WhatsApp.**

[insufficient space while updating WhatsApp on CyanogenMod](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/92900/86559)

Comment: A "dead data folder" on a new phone after a factory reset is pretty unlikely.

Comment: @Izzy, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for past few weeks. Following solutions worked for me.

It seems a bug in Google play store update.

1. Goto google play store in Settings >> apps >> all >> Google Play Store
2. Open by clicking the app
3. Then click Uninstall Updates.

Now goto play store and install any apps without getting "Insufficient Storage Available".

Comment: Well there is no Uninstall Updates option at all. My old phone had one. What can I do now? There are only Force Stop and Disable options available apart from the Clear Cache etc options.

Comment: Try to install old versions of play store.

Answer (score 0):

I face this problem many times due to facebook application. It automatically expands its size internally. i have taken some screen shots of this

[image: scrren 1]

[image: screen 2]

[image: screen 3]

[image: screen 4]

Do check timings in them... Sometimes even like 5 min interval gap this problem used to occur. But imo you won't be having this problem as internal memory your phone has is quite large.

try this then--->

Settings-->Applications--> All-->

Find Google play store, Google play services and google play services framework.

Open each of them and click "clear data".

Now close every app. A restart Will be good not mandatory though.

Open google play store and "accept" agreement. You can download apps now.