# insufficient space while updating WhatsApp and other apps

Tags: google-play-store, whatsapp-messenger, insufficient-memory, 4.3-jelly-bean

Whatsapp has forced everyone to update their apps before June 8th. Everytime, I tried to update it I got the 'insufficient storage space' error and now, on June 8th, I can't access my Whatsapp. As of now, I have:

- **2.43 GB available on internal card**
- **5.69 GB available on SD Card**

I have **rooted** Sony Xperia SP running on Android 4.3. 
I have tried every possible thing on the Internet. The problem is Google Play Store is allowing me to install some apps but giving error on other apps installation/update. I was successfully able to download Sound Cloud and Clean Master, but couldn't update Whatsapp or install System Cleanup. I even tried to download System Cleanup manually through apk file but it gave me the same error. I think my solution is somewhat mentioned by these two people here:
[insufficient space while updating WhatsApp on CyanogenMod](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92900/insufficient-space-while-updating-whatsapp-on-cyanogenmod/92912#92912?newreg=68cd7b238f9542dfb96e4bfa3f6ca687)

However, the problem is I can't download System Clean up and I don't know how to manually delete dead folders

**Update**
This is how far I have come:

- I can see all the contents of /data and /data/data
- I even deleted some whatsapp related files that I don't remember. They neither did any good nor harm the phone.
- I have read that I have to delete 'dead data folders' and 'affected libraries'. However, I have no idea exactly what to delete or how to know which libraries are affected!

Comment: Please see this new article 2017/02/10 [10 most useless apps and games for Android](http://www.androidauthority.com/most-useless-apps-android-749163). Most prominent, but specifically named in the list: Clean Master (along with quote-Booster apps, Anti-Virus apps, and Task Killers-unquote)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing 'cache' through stock recovery or any appropiate apps and **reboot** your phone.

If the same problem presist, then try clearing google play store app **cache** and try **clear data**.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Wary question: Are you familiar with the backgrounds of the issue? Clearing 'cache' through stock recovery clears up the `/cache` partition, which is not involved here (the error relates to the `/data` partition only, see our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for details). Clearing cache/data from the play store app might have a minimal positive side effect here, but wouldn't be a solution (not enough space freed). So how should the proposed actions solve the issue?

Comment: @Izzy can you point me into some direction? i have done almost everything and still I can't update/install certain apps

Comment: @user2851347 not further than the link I've provided with my previous comment. Have you checked that? In our tag-wikis we often sum up our knowledge on a topic, and link to questions we feel "important"/"especially helpful" on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @devwaseem, clearing cache helps. Most data hogging culprits are google maps, google photos, gallery. You may try uninstalling maps and then install whatsapp to see if it helps. This has worked many a times back in the day with the cheap phones I used to own. However, you may run into the same trouble while reinstalling  maps (or anything else you momentarily removed) again.

Comment: thankyou for your quick response. I have tried all this. I have cleared the cache and cleared the data of Google Play Store. I have even cleared cache of individual apps. I do have space on my internal storage. Almost 2 GB. I don't want to uninstall Whatsapp. I am trying to avoid that. I think I am having a culprit old update file of an app that's causing this error but I don't know which one is it!

Comment: You mention you have a rooted phone. Why not install titanium backup and get rid of some bloatware sony apps?

Comment: Can you please tell me the steps for this? Like how should i go about it without erasing all my data?

Comment: You could try the steps listed out on the latter section of this [post](http://www.howtogeek.com/115533/how-to-disable-or-uninstall-android-bloatware/) . Again - DO NOT proceed to remove apps that are core essentials to the functioning of your phone. If you do not know what the app is, you best leave it alone. And before you go about removing apps, it would be wise to take a complete backup of all applications (both system as well as external) via the same app itself.

Comment: Okay so I have successfully backed up my data using Titanium App. It's beyond me how I was able to install Titanium app and not been able to update Whatsapp or Play Store.
Before I proceed, I want to make sure that all I am required to do now is to freeze certain apps to see which of them is being the bloatware app? The idea is that once i do that, i'd be able to update/install anything i want, right?

Comment: I did freeze some apps and disabled the others. Nothing worked. Still can't update anything :/

Comment: Freezing  /  disabling does not mean that you've deleted the app. It still is there, occupying the same space that it was earlier. Another option for you would be to safely bakup your current whatsapp on Google Drive ( There is an option in settings) and uninstall it. Then reinstall a fresh copy of it, so that it redownloads everything off of google drive. Someone over at [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2483034) has documented the bloatware apps that can be safely removed. Again, please take a backup and exercise caution while dealing with system apps.

Comment: Thankyou @blueren
The only way to solve the problem was doing a factory reset on the phone. Now, everything is working fine!